# Displaying different mysql rows in a "List style";

Tags: php, mysql

Ok a weird title, but it's my question;

This is my function to display data:

public function notLoggedIn($whichtable, $whichrow, $link, $preference, $dag, $uur)
    {
        $this->newfunction = new functions;
        $getvalue = $this->newGet();

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $whichtable WHERE $whichrow = '$preference'");
    $combine = "table $dag";    
    echo "<table style='float:left; width:100%;'>";     

    while ($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $maandag = $rij["Maandag"];
        $uren = $rij['Uren'];
        $id = $rij['id'];           
        if(!$header)
        {
            echo "<th></th><th>Maandag</th>";
            $header= true;
        }
        $getkleur = explode(",", $maandag); 
        if($header == 1)
        {
            echo "<tr><th style='width:20%; border-right:1px dotted #000;'>".$uren."</th>";
            echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #999; width:100%; height:40px;'>".$getkleur[0]."</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td></td><td style='width:100%;'><b><a style='background-color:$getkleur[4]; color:#fff;' href=''>".$getkleur[3]."</b>";
            echo "<b><a style='color:#906;' href=''>". $getkleur[2]."</b></a></td></tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

It's for an application to show different schedules for school students.
This code displays just one day. Every day has a different row.

But i want all rows displayed on one page.
But because of use explode this gets hard.

And I'm not going to type 5 different while loops for every row and explode it again and display it.

I should get all on one page in a some kind of "list", for example:

Monday:
// Whats scheduled for monday

Tuesday:
// Whats scheduled for tuesday,

Etc. etc. 
Till friday.

EDIT: Table example:
[image]

(Maandag = Monday, Dinsdag = Tuesday, Woensdag = Wednesday, Thursday = Donderdag, Friday = Vrijdag, Uren = Hours) translated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the tables you are using

From the code sample above, I assume you got all days loaded inside $rij.

Thus, with that assumption, you can load all days inside a separate array, and reference the results with a foreach, something like the following:

```
$days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

foreach ($days as $currentDay) {
    $day = $rij[$currentDay];  // will reference $rij["Monday"] and so on
    (...)
    if (!$header) {
        echo "<th></th><th>$currentDay</th>";
        $header = true;
    }
    $getkleur = explode(",", $currentDay); 
    if($header == 1) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

(added the days in English, use the Dutch ones)

Comment: Thnx alot, i try some things with it:P, in my option this doesn't yet solve my problem, but i test it. ( I edit my question in a few mins with a screenshot of the Table!).

Comment: I need to get the info from the SELECT query, which the while did. Or should this get displayed in a while loop which takes everthing from the query?, I update my question with a screenshot of mine Table:p

Comment: Ok it does load everthing now, and see my edited question, with the Table screenshot; Uren for hours. Now everthing is displayedl ike this: Monday: 1. index 1.index 1.index 1.index etc. And than again Monday 2. index 2. index, the 1 and 2 being the hours till 8 hours which is one day. But it should get displayed like this: Monday: 1. index 2. index 3. index etc. than again Tuesday: 1. index 2. index etc. I hope u understand my point:P ALL hours should get displayed ea day.